# Should osx brand server tags be synonyms of each other or the main non-server OS tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I would like to suggest that [snow-leopard-server](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/snow-leopard-server) and any other such variant of the given Server Software names be synonymized to [osx-server](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx-server).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The theory, at least, is that some questions are about OS X Server in general, and some are about a specific version of OS X server—in the same fashion that some questions are tagged [osx](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx) and some [snow-leopard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/snow-leopard).

Comment: Isn't that the point of the synonym though? To allow people to use derivatives to identify the specific version, but keeping them grouped in the tag interface by general topic for applicability purposes? [edit] I really hope that made sense. It makes sense to me :/.

Comment: I guess I was mistaken. Thanks for clarifying that.